# Playing with lost finger

Tags: chord-theory, physical-limitations

I've been playing for many years and love my guitars. Sadly I lost my index finger a few weeks ago. It's pretty devastating. Any ideas on playing using only 3 finger chords? I'm never going to get back where I was, but I'm hoping I can get to a stage where I can at least have fun and be a bit entertaining. Thanks!

Comment: Please see the duplicate question to start -- feel free to post another question if you encounter any specific issues!

Comment: Both Jango Rheinhardt and Tonny Iommi played and still are playing guitar with a few fingers missing.